# [DJI Windows SDK]flightControllerHandler is null

Tags: dji-sdk

I'm trying to get the altitude of the drone using FlightControllerHandler class, but when I execute my program, it says that flightControllerHandler is null.

My controller is plugged on, my PC is connected to the drone's WiFi, still null.

**My code :**

```
    public Parser videoParser;
    public FlightControllerHandler flightControllerHandler;
    
    private async void Page_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if(flightControllerHandler != null) 
        { 
            var b = flightControllerHandler.GetAltitudeAsync();
            lblAltitude1.Text = "Altitude : " + b.ToString();
        }
    }
```

Any solutions to fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to get the handler from the sdk.

```
var res = await DJISDKManager.Instance.ComponentManager.GetFlightControllerHandler(0, 0).SetAircraftNameAsync(new StringMsg { value = toSet });
                            message = String.Format("Set aircraft's name: {0}", res.ToString());
```

Have a look at the demo on github.

Comment: Hello, even with the demo, it's still null for me